# Open a file from the src directory (Java)

Tags: java, pdf, intellij-idea

I've written a short documentation for my Java program. When clicking on the menu *Help -> Documentation* the default PDF reader of the OS should open the `documentation.pdf`.

I'm trying to open the PDF which is located in the directory `src/doc` with `Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("doc/documentation.pdf"));` in `Controller.java`.

However, Java does not find the file. When I open the icon for the program with `primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon/icon_512x512.png"));` it works perfectly in `Main.java`.

Here you can see layout of my IntelliJ project.

```
src
├── META-INF
├── de
│   └── myapp
│       ├── model
│       │   └── *.java
│       ├── view
│       │   └── *.java
│       ├── Main.java
│       └── Controller.java
├── doc
│   └── documentation.pdf
└── icon
    └── icon_512x512.png
```

My stack

- IntelliJ 2016.2
- Java 1.8.0_77

Comment: Is the doc Directory part ob the class path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `new Image("icon/icon_512x512.png")` because internally it gets is from the context `ClassLoader` which is not the case of `new File("doc/documentation.pdf")` that gets it from the user working directory in case of a relative path, so you could simply apply the same logic.

```
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = contextClassLoader.getResource("doc/documentation.pdf");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(resource.toURI()));
```

Answer (score 1):

3-rd party applications can not access src dir in your application, in case, when your app assemble in jar archive. You should place your file separately from src.

Of course, java find icons, because it's java API.
You can access any resources in src folder through follow methods:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/in/src");
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/in/src");
```

If your app is NOT assemble in JAR - try provide full path to file like this:

```
  URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/in/src");
  File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Answer (score 1):

The files from Classpath can be loaded by using `ClassLoader`'s `getResourceAsStream` Method.
So you can try with generating an Input stream object

```
InputStream is = Controller.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("doc/documentation.pdf");
```

And After generating Input Stream you can read it by Java Program.